# Re-arranging a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string to create 2 parallel arrays, process the letters in the string from left to right, inserting each letter into the first array in alphabetical order, one letter at a time. During this process, each letter is assigned an integer value in the second array as follows:

The first letter has a value of 0.
If the new letter is the first or last in the array, its value is one more than the value of the adjacent letter.
Otherwise, it is one more than the larger value of the two adjacent values. If the letter is already in the array, the new letter is placed before the existing letter. Once the two arrays are created, output the letters in order of their value, from left to right, starting with the 0, then all of the 1s, then all of the 2s, etc.
For example, if someone input "PYTHONN" into the function, it would output "PHYOTNN."

I tried to use if-else statements to try to solve this problem, but my code got messy and I kept recieving errors. This is my code:

```
def ltnb(i):
    return i.split()

def listByValue(input):
    process_str=input
    converted_list=[]
    test_v=[]
    arr_1=[]
    arr_2=[]
    full_list=[]
    x=0
    for letter in process_str:
        test_v.clear()
        for i in converted_list:
            test_v.append(ltnb(i)[0])
        test_v.append(letter)
        test_v.sort()
        
        if len(converted_list)==0:
            number=0
        elif x==0:
            x=test_v.index(letter)
            number=int(ltnb(converted_list[x-1])[1])+1
        elif x==len(converted_list):
            x=test_v.index(letter)
            number=int(ltnb(converted_list[x])[1])+1
        else:
            x=test_v.index(letter)
            number=max(int(ltnb(converted_list[x-1])[1]), int(ltnb(converted_list[x])[1]))  
        converted_list.insert(x, f"{letter} {number}")
        for i in range(0,len(converted_list)):
            ltnb(converted_list)[1]
```

I also couldn't figure out what and how to return the correct code. Is there anything wrong with my code and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: The `for` loop at the end doesn't do anything. It calls `ltnb()` on each element of the list, but doesn't do anything with the result.

Comment: Don't use `input` as a variable name, it's the name of a standard built-in function. You could just use `process_str` as the parameter name.

Comment: Why are you creating all the strings in `converted_list` just to split them up? Use tuples.

Comment: You don't seem to be processing the input string in alphabetical order. You're never inserting anything in `arr_1` or `arr_2`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. Perhaps, could you create code to help? I was stuck on just even getting it to return something...

Also, when you said I didn't put anything into `arr_1` or `arr_2` I created the lists but figured I didn't need them.

Comment: You can "return something" if you put `return converted_list` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar Returning the list doesn't return the letters in the right order, it also returns the number.

Comment: I know. That's why it returns "something", not the correct answer.

Comment: I mean, I tried that but it gives me errors:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: If you fill in the two arrays correctly, you can use `zip()` to combine them. Then you can sort that by the numbers from the 2nd array to return the letters in the correct order.

Comment: If you use a tuple you don't need to split it, it's already split. But I'm not really sure what those `f"{letter} {number}"` are for -- how do they correspond to the instructions?

Comment: I couldn't do `list.append(x, y)` it only let me do `f"{x} {y}` Also basically does the same thing btw

Comment: That's not a tuple, you have to put it in parentheses. `list.append((x, y))`.

Comment: But shouldn't it be something like `arr_1.append(x)` and `arr_2.append(y)`?

Comment: I mean, technically yes, but I don't really need arr_1 and arr_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the "how can I solve this problem?" part, a working implementation:

```py
s = 'PYTHONN'

L, V = [], [-1]
for c in s:
    L += c
    L.sort()
    i = L.index(c)
    V.insert(i+1, max(V[i:i+2])+1)
print(''.join(sorted(L, key=lambda _: V.pop(1))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU-xDoIwFNz7FW9rmwJJnQwJuwNBB0NiCDEIJValbWhN4FtcWHTwj_wbq-hN7y7v3d27PczojlpN0_3q2nD5elpIAG9229U6yzBCaQC5V4oygCLkJWp1DzVIBTZG4JECS6Cex8jq3hH6JdIfpZFUjRhIPUu5p1b4Dcl4AF01kLyQsWSLkjJOkemlcgTj6KSlIh8r0RAffxZjcqm6Q1PBPvYmRhvCqcfc-Ff8_8Ab)

The extra `-1` just makes the code easier.